How to execute a Spring Boot project with Maven?
I developed a Spring Boot (Java) backend API project and execute it with Maven. I would like to Dockerize my project to make it easier to execute.
Unfortunately, I only know how to execute my project with IntelliJ IDE, so I don't know what to do to execute my project on a command line. This is giving me trouble when writing my dockerfile.
My hosted project can be found on GitHub.
I tried to specify a goal in the pom.xml but nothing really changed. How can I find out how to execute my application on the command line? Thank you in advance !

This is all smoke and mirrors really. The true heart of the matter is... that you don't know Java. You may know the language maybe, but you don't know the tooling. To get to a question like this you would need to have zero knowledge of what an executable jar is, nor that the JDK has a "java" command. That's all Java 101, you should know it. Up to you to acknowledge that fact and act on it.

Let me share a sample Dockerfile. It installs Maven, builds a JAR file and installs Java runtime. The last line is for starting the application. Hope it will give you some hints.
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-21 AS build
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests
FROM eclipse-temurin:21-alpine
COPY --from=build /target/rest-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar rest-api.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","rest-api.jar"]


java version is 21 so use eclipse-temurin:21-jdk and eclipse-temurin:21-alpine

If you want not have to deal with dockerfile you can use
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin
add a little config in pom and it will generate an optimized dockerfile for you and deploy it to an image repository.
thank

I had learned the following steps for Dockerized/Containered my application. Assuming you had docker installed locally

Define your DockerFile in your Project Main Folder. Below is my sample one:
FROM openjdk:21 //openjdk:21 is the source image of jdk which is used to execute following commands. However, there are many multiple jdk images available from which you can use
WORKDIR /app -- It states that /app is directory used inside the docker
COPY target/crudapplication.jar crudapplication.jar -- It will copies the source jar from project target folder into the /app directory (inside docker)
EXPOSE 8080 -- Defines the port on which the application will run. However, we can define any port.
CMD ["java", "-jar", "crudapplication.jar"] -- this mentions the command used to run the spring application



Docker command to create docker image of your application
$ docker build -t crudapplication:latest -- t argument mentions the docker image name (crudapplication) and tag (latest) of your docker image

Docker run command for running the application outside of your IDE
$ docker run -dp 8080:8080 crudapplication:latest -- -d argument mentions above command will runs in a detached mode. Means the logs of your Spring Application will not be printed in the console. Use can use docker logs command to see the logs of your application. However -d argument is optional.
-p mentions the port on which your application will be running.


Thanks
